# How to update a state for nested object in react js which is DeviceProperties in my example ( IPAddress, username, and password)

Tags: json, reactjs, state

How to update a state for nested object in react js which is DeviceProperties in my example ( IPAddress, username, and password)

```
[
  {
    "DeviceId": 217,
    "Name": "My Name",
    "PairedNetworkName": null,
    "Description": null,
    "VersionNumber": null,
    "DeviceProperties": {
      "IPAddress": "185.213.180.129:9900",
      "UserName": "admin",
      "Password": "123456789",
    },
  }
]
```

Comment: Using setState for full object

Answer (score 0):

In your reducer:

```
[...]
case UPDATE_DEVICE_PROPERTIES:
  return {
    ...device,
    DeviceProperties: { [...] }
  }
break;
[...]
```

In this example i am showing how you can update one device, if you already selected this device. As i gues, you would iterate through your devices[] - array and find the correct device. Then you would use object destructuring ( the three dots ...OBJECT, e.g. ...device) to update only the necessary parts.

More on object destructuring:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Official redux docs for updating objects:
https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers/#handling-actions

Answer (score 0):

You can access nested object value using **Dot Notation** e.g. `DeviceProperties.IPAddress`. Like if you are trying to store only the IPAddress then you can using

`this.setState({ IPAddress: DeviceProperties.IPAddress })`

Comment: deviceSettings: {
        name: '',
        // deviceId: null,
        iPAddress: '',
        userName: '',
        password: '',
        // name: this.props.device.name,
        // deviceId: this.props.device.deviceId,
        // IPAddress: this.props.device.deviceProperties.iPAddress,
        // UserName: this.props.device.deviceProperties.userName,
        // Password: this.props.device.deviceProperties.password, 
        serialNumber: '',
        pairedNetworkName: '',
        description: '',
        deviceId: '',
      },

Comment: i have like this in my state and cannot delete the deviceSettings becasue i am using it in reducers and saga

Comment: so from this point how can i reach IPAddress, username and password with the device settings

Comment: you can access IPAddress using, deviceSettings.IPAddress

Comment: Syntax will be like this.setState({ 'deviceSettings.IPAddress': DeviceProperties.IPAddress })

Comment: The big problem for me was that i am accessing ipaddress but i cant update it

Comment: can you send me your email please to send you the complete code and to know what is the problem

Comment: We can chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206257/mayuri-s-kulkarni

Comment: i cant contact you because i need reputations

Comment: i tried what you told me but it doesn't work i already tried i before but the props stays the same

Comment: Can you post what exactly you are trying

Comment: it is some how long it cant be here since there are inputs, state  and props

Comment: if you can help me to send it to you by email